# How to create a Google form programatically with python ?Is it possible to do so by appscript and python interfacing or something like that?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

How to create a Google form programatically with python ? Do they provide some api like drive api  to do so ? Is it possible to interface python with Google appscript ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38H7WpsTD0M Here they are talking about creating a form with a form using app script . Thank you in advance .

Comment: This is not a proper question for SO.

Comment: Is there some api to access the Google forms like the Drive python api ?

Comment: A quick Google search gives you an answer.  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/handlingforms

Comment: https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/write-google-spreadsheet-from-python/ - Wanted to know if something like this was available. I saw this piece of code and the repository is dead now . Is something similar available for Google Forms with the new sdk ? Or is it possible to interface Google app script with python ?

Comment: Yes its possible to interface with apps script. look at content service published to run as owner and run anonymous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your only option is to interface through apps script, the question becomes very similar to other questions on this site regarding that topic. look at the apps script documentation on contentService. publish one running as owner and with permissions to anonymous. then use doGet/doPost to communicate with the script like a regular backend.